# is there an equivalent of the R DT package for python3?

Tags: python, datatables

I discovered **DT** (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) to manage **DataTables** (JavaScript library from https://www.datatables.net/) in **R** but an not sure of which current **python3** package matches DT best. I find a number of 'datatable..' python packages but they do not seem to be about the same in-memory js library.

Can someone please point me tho the best alternative to the R 'DT' library in python3?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [itables](https://pypi.org/project/itables/) is a good candidate.  Another option is [qgrid](https://pypi.org/project/qgrid/0.3.2/)